# Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word(…)..

Tags: angular, typescript

app.template.html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
         <button class= "btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddMessage()">RANDOM BUTTON</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
         <article class="panel panel-default" *ngFor = "let latestmessage of messages" >
            <div class="panel-body">
               {{ latestmessage.content }}
            </div>
         </article>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from './message.model';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    messages: Message[] = [
        new Message('hello')
    ];

    onAddMessage() {
        const rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
        const msg = new Message(rnd + ' is a awsome number');
        this.messages.push(msg);
    }
}
```

message.model.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Message(){
    constructor(public content: string){}
}
```

This code is build in angularjs2 and nodejs .I created a button.when i click on button it give me response like this hello     99 number is an awesome number.what is reserved word in this code?? anyone can help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the Message class with parentheses after its name `()`:

```
export class Message(){
```

You may change the message.model.ts to:

message.model.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Message{
    constructor(public content: string){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks  ! I was facing the same issue and so bad of me too miss out such a silly mistake !

Comment: @Amit shame on you haha! Just playing. That's not a problem though, there is a good reason for us to have created intelisense, there so many language aspects these days that some times we get stucked in such a silly detail. Also, I guess Typescript parser have failed at this point of naming classes  incorectly because the syntax error thrown is not clear at all. Anyways, I'm glad that I could help somehow. Cheers :{D

Answer (score 9):

I got a similar error when I was using `await` but the nearest parent function was not `async`.

Answer (score 1):

I want to mention, just in case someone else can have it, that for me, it turned out that I forgot to put the opening bracket `{` after the method name:

```js
self.myMethod = function(text, iconId) 
  let $text = $(iconId);
  ...
}
```

Instead of:

```js
self.myMethod = function(text, iconId) {
  let $text = $(iconId);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using javascript classes the `#` prefixed variable scopes privately into `this`, thus

```
let #defaultImageSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(expImage);       // yields the error
```

should read

```
this.#defaultImageSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(expImage);
```